# SimplePie.inc file is gone, what do I replace it with?

Tags: rss, simplepie

I am trying to follow this tutorial on how to set up SimplePie.

http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/55-adding-rss-content-with-simplepie/

At 10:40 he adds

```
    require_once('inc/simplepie.inc');
```

to get simplepie library. However in SimplePie 1.3.1 simplepie.inc is not included. What should I replace it with instead?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `require_once('autoloader.php');` (adjusted to your path, of course) as per the [1.3 migration notes](http://simplepie.org/wiki/misc/release_notes/simplepie_1.3).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ryan. I use MAMP. In my htdocs I have one folder. Within that folder I have index.php and autoloader.php. In my index.php I have stated require_once('demo/autoloader.php'); but it still doesn't work. Do you have a fix?

Comment: Try using just `require_once('autoloader.php')`. The path is relative to whatever file you're in.

Comment: Do I need to include any other files other than autoloader.php?

Comment: Oh, you need to download the other files as well. Alternatively, grab the compiled version and just use that: http://simplepie.org/downloads/simplepie_1.3.1.compiled.php